# How to dispatch action on NavLink click in React?

Tags: reactjs

After clicking on NavLink I need to:

1. Dispatch an action
2. Go to the url

Does anybody know how to dispatch an action before going to the url?
The url has no additional parameters after slash.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried passing an `onClick` prop to the `NavLink`? If you did, you need to provide more context to your question, code snippets etc.

Comment: Tried, but it doesn't work. Finally decided to use <div> instead of <NavLink> with WithRouter and onClick { dispatch(action); props.history.push('/url') }